# Anchor tag inside the div is showing outside the div on minimizing the browser

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

When I minimizing the browser the text within anchor tag is coming outside the div.

```html
<ul style="font-size:18px;">
  <li >Goto you <a href="https://www.youstable.com/hosting/web-hosting" >https://www.youstable.com/hosting/web-hosting</a> and select the hosting plan you would like to go with.</li>
<li style="list-style-type:none">
<center><img src="images/hosting.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Paid Hosting"></center>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use padding and overflow properties/attributes in css

Comment: Use css on anchor tag, I have tried it but it doesn't work. See the image that I had shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added property word-break

```
<ul style="font-size:18px;">
  <li >Goto you <a style="word-break: break-all;" href="https://www.youstable.com/hosting/web-hosting" >https://www.youstable.com/hosting/web-hosting</a> and select the hosting plan you would like to go with.</li>
<li style="list-style-type:none">
<center><img src="images/hosting.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Paid Hosting"></center>
</li>
</ul>
```